# Generating HTML list from hierarchy MySQL Table

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a hierarchy table like so

```
id| name         | parent_id | header 
1 | Assets       | 0         | Y
2 | Fixed Assets | 1         | Y
3 | Asset One    | 2         | N
4 | Income       | 1         | N
```

I pull this data via axios and trying to render in the below way

I am trying to generate a UL LI list like so

```
<ul>
    <li id="asset-main-id">
        Assets
        <ul>
            <li id="fixed-asset-header">
                Fixed Assets
                <ul>
                    <li id="fa-asset-child-one">Asset One</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="asset-child">Income Receiveables</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It would multiple parent-child relationship meaning it could go till 10 levels. I am confused on how to achieve this.

Can someone guide me to achieve this?

Dummy Payload

```js
[{id: 1, name: assets, parent_id: 0, header:Y}, {id: 2, name: Fixed Assets, parent_id: 1, header:Y} ....]
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: MySQL version 5.7

Comment: the question is about how to render or how to represent the data? if you are trying to achieve one of them, can you attach a dummy payload?

Comment: I have attached the payload @OmerShacham

Comment: @Rehan check my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I only would like to give you an alternative.
It would be much easier if you can change the way you represent the data. It may depend to have control over the service which you pull the data.

Example:

```
var data = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Assets",
  "header": true,
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Fixed Assets",
      "header": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Asset One",
          "header": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Income",
      "header": false
    }
  ]
}
```

After that, this example would lead you a solution: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/tree-view.html

Comment: I have already looked at that example. Since I use `JqxWidget` and I render the tree in a dropdown, the widgets need the data in the ul,li way.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the data struct as @The_Cute_Hedgehod offer nested parent-child relation.

I can add an example how to convert your current ds to it.

after you got the given payload, you can always render it using custom vue component

you can find full working example here:
https://codepen.io/omer-shacham/pen/xxbrxdO

example data

```
var data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Assets",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Fixed Assets",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Asset One",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Income",
    }
  ]
}
```

example template

```
<template>
    <li>
    {{ name }}
        <ul v-if="children.size > 0">
            <TreeNode v-for="child in children" :node="child"/>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>
```

and your root app

```
<ul>
   <TreeNode v-for="child in root" :child="child"/>
</ul>
```

Comment: What happens if child have some header? Will it still work?

Comment: @Rehan how do you want to express it in the html?